# click function after dynamically changing data using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a click function inside a `div` with some nested children tags such as `span`, `td`, etc. However, these nested tags are loaded dynamically, mostly using `ajax()`. The returned result is displayed using `.html(data)` function. However, once the data is changed and new tags are added, the old javascript written to detect the clicks no longer work.

I want to know if there is a way to make this work?

An example of what i am talking about can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V4Sfw/).

Comment: Look into the [3-argument version of jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to attach the event handler on the wrapper element like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4Sfw/1/

```
$("#testing").on("click", "span", function() {
    alert("now?");
});
$("#testing").html("<span>How about now?</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach handlers that always work, as long you know the structure of the loaded HTML.

Comment: This is true but `.live()` has been deprecated for a long time.  The current release uses a 3-argument version of `.on()`.

Comment: That seems to be right. It's been a while since used jQuery.